# Function and procedure with cursor (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for asking these question here. I've found online and in book, but didn't got something similar.

1. Create the function float `sf_getAverageGrade(@sname nchar(10))`.

Requirements:

- The function returns -1 if there is no student called `@sname`;
- returns -2 if there are more than one student called `@sname`;
- returns the average grade of student sname if he/she has at least one course grade;
- returns null if student `@sname` has no course grade.

I tried to write it like this:(**my question is it seems logical but it doesn't work. Please help me figure out why. Thanks**)

```
CREATE FUNCTION sf_getAverageGrade
    (@sname NCHAR(10))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @n NCHAR(10), @countsname INTEGER, @countgrade INTEGER, @avggrade FLOAT 
    SET @n = (SELECT sname FROM student)

    SET @countsname = (SELECT COUNT(sno) FROM student WHERE sname = @sname)

    SET @countgrade = (SELECT COUNT(grade) 
                       FROM sc 
                       GROUP BY sno 
                       HAVING sno = (SELECT sno FROM student WHERE sname = @sname))

    SET @avggrade = (SELECT AVG(grade) FROM sc 
                     GROUP BY sno 
                     HAVING sno = (SELECT sno FROM student WHERE sname = @sname))

    IF @n <> @sname
        RETURN -1
    ELSE IF @countsname > 1
        RETURN -2
    ELSE IF @countgrade >= 1
        RETURN @avggrade
    ELSE IF @countgrade = 0
        RETURN 'null'

    RETURN 0
END
```

2.Create a stored procedure `sp_displayGradeInRow(@sname nchar(10))`

The stored procedure displays information of two rows:

- the first row includes ‘name’, all course names selected by @sname and ‘average grade’
- the second row includes @sname, the grades and average grade. (Using cursor to get course names and grades)

Show the stored procedure result when the parameter @sname equals ‘Jack’

**For this one, I just don't know how to let these information display in two rows.**

Thank for your help. I just need some clue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We are not here to do your homework for you. And tell your teacher/professor that scalar functions are horribly inefficient. And that using a cursor inside of a scalar function is borderline criminal behavior. They should be teaching you set based approaches to problems like this.

Comment: You should be able to do the same with a sub query and maybe a case statement combined. Forget about functions and cursos they are very slow and not recommended in a real world scenario. Also the cursors lock the records while the process is not completed and this is terrible because no one will be able to write or read the data.

Comment: @Juan *"Forget about functions... they are very slow and not recommended in a real world scenario"*. This simply isn't true. Like Sean said, **Scalar** functions are slow, as are Multi-line Table Functions. Inline Table-Value functions, however, can be incredibly quick and **are** recommended in the real world. Don't lump Scalar, Multi-line Table and inline Table-Vale in the same category. They're all different.

Comment: SET @n = (SELECT sname FROM student) missing the where condition

Comment: @Larnu I think what I was trying to say is that it will force a table scan making your query very slow. They can be fast for a scenario where your not going to have a lot records to process and then display in an application.

Comment: @Juan I still don't agree with you. An inline table-value function isn't going to force a table scan on it's own; one could, depending on what it does and your `WHERE` and `ON` clauses, but that's not to say it will. Far from it. If, however, you have something that proves otherwise, or a link to an article that confirms what you say is true, I'd love to see it. It could result in quite the cognitive shift in the SQL Server community.

Comment: @Larnu this is a scalar function, every records needs to enter in the function to return a value. I just created the scenario in my instance just to check again the execution plan.

Comment: @Juan Ok, but I was specifically talking about inline table-value functions. You've just been talking about "functions" as a whole. hence my arguement. I agree a scalar function will cause performance problems (as i said before), but inline table-value functions, scalar functions and multiline table functions are not created equally. You can't just say "functions are bad"; they simply isn't true.

Comment: @Larnu I think I missed the scalar function when I said functions. I agreed not to say all functions are bad.

Comment: Sorry, but I've tried to find something in book and online, I didn't see any similar concept. Our teacher asked us to do in this way, so I just wanted to know some clue, not the whole answer. Thanks everyone.